# Apache httpd.conf file missing

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I've looked on

- etc/apache/httpd.conf
- /etc/httpd/conf/http.conf
- /etc/httpd/http.conf

Is there somewhere else where this file can be?? Am I missing something...?

Comment: Try typing "locate httpd.conf"

Comment: it depends on the os, do a locate httpd.conf

Comment: typing it in the terminal you mean? if it's that I got **-bash: locate: command not found**

Comment: In xampp its in apache/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command on the command line:

```
apachectl configtest
```

This should attempt to test the config, and it should also tell you where it's testing the config from.

Comment: It does not. But `apachectl -V` seems to.

Answer (score 1):

run the following command:

```
cd /
sudo find *.conf
```

this should find all .conf files for you, just look threw and see what there is

More information on this command located here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/find